# Problema para acceder al FrontEnd de Zabbix

Tags: linux, centos7

Tengo el problema de no puedo acceder al FrontEnd de Zabbix.
La cuestion es que ya instale todo lo necesario para poder usarlo presente en esta guia: https://www.fosslinux.com/7705/how-to-install-and-configure-zabbix-on-centos-7.htm. El tema es que, llegando a la parte del FrontEnd utiliza su ip para poder acceder a el. He usado una ip dinamica, una estatica y hasta el localhost pero no pude acceder a el.
Si alguien puede ayudarme se le agradeceria muchisimo.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Al final el problema se resolvia facil, solo tenia que entrar en las configuraciones de red de la Maquina Virtual y crear un nuevo adaptador de red de tipo `Host-Only Adapter`.